# Scope of variable in a macro

Tags: c++, c, macros, scope

In a file xyz.c

```
int p=2;  //global

#define sum(p,i) p+i

int main()
{
    printf("%d", sum(5,6));
}
```

output here would be 11 (and not 8); why?

Comment: You can't try it and view the output?

Comment: @chris i want the reason also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output is definitely `11`.
Because `p` is not considered as a variable inside the macro, it's just like a token which has a invocation value; e.g. `(5,6)`. The scope of the token is limited to macro scope.

Suppose you change the macro as below, then the output will be 8:

```
#define sum(q,i) p+i
      //   ^^^ token 'q' is unused, so (5,6) is replaced with 'p+6'
```

Answer (score 9):

Pre-processing happens before compilation. When the preprocessor encounters `sum`, it will replace it with the contents, i.e. your code translates to:

```
int p=2; //global

int main()
{
   printf("%d", 5+6);
}
```

so output `11`. The preprocessor has no knowledge of any of your variables.

Answer (score 3):

The  problem you can see if you see the .i(intermadiate file) of you program .The steps of a program to executable includes some steps as follows

```
1.preprocessing
2.compilation
3.assembler for object code
4.linking
```

use the command as follows for first step -preprocessing

> `cpp <your program>.c -o <any name to output>.i`

if you do this then after excuting this you can see the .i file of your program there you wil see as follows

```
int p=2;



int main()
{
    printf("%d", 5 +6);
}
```

It is clearly visible why the answer is 11,as all the preprocessor replaces the value what you given first then the compilation done,so there is no 'p' to be used for global p after preprocesing.There is no p for next steps to use in the program.

so you got the answer 11.